# Google Docs API returns a 503 Service Unavailable when uploading a file. Has something changed?

Tags: java, android, google-docs-api

I have applications that make use of the Google Docs API.  Up until recently, uploads using the HTTP endpoints has been working fine.  Recently, uploading has suddenly started erroring.  The first call to create a session (which returns the resumable URL) works fine, and returns a resumable URL.  Attempting to then send the file contents to the resumable URL throws a 503.

The relevant part of the code throwing the error is this:

```
        URL url = new URL(resumableFileUploadUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("client_id", OAuth2Client.CLIENT_ID);
        conn.addRequestProperty("client_secret", OAuth2Client.CLIENT_SECRET);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + GetAuthToken());

        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileContents.length())); //back to 0
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type", "text/xml");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileContents.length()));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Slug", fileName);

        if(isUpdate)
        {
            conn.setRequestProperty("If-Match", "*");
            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        }
        else
        {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }

        conn.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "GPSLogger for Android");


        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(fileContents);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        newLocation = conn.getHeaderField("location");
```

The above code is used both for creating the session to get the resumable URL as well as posting file contents to the resumable URL.

Which is part of [this](https://github.com/mendhak/googledocs-upload-sample/blob/master/src/com/mendhak/example/PureJavaUploadActivity.java) Android activity.  I am including a link to the original activity as it would probably be quite easy to reproduce the problem by simply cloning the repository.  The code has remained untouched for a year.

Has something changed recently that would cause this?

I would like to avoid having to use Google Drive's APIs for now as I have not changed any code and the same code is being used in a few of my other applications in the field.

Comment: Have you tried a different Google account? Since a month or two ago, my account (and seemingly a few other peoples) have returned 503 ServiceUnavailable errors from GData Google services. In my case, YouTube and Google Play Movies are completely busted -> https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube/IsDSzuY8NbE The raw response from the YouTube/Movies API is "ServiceNotAvailable" with a type of "GData" and a status code of 503 :(

Comment: My Fiddler trace is in this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4597

Answer (score 0):

One of the most annoying “features” is the undocumented rate limit when requesting images, each request of which must be authenticated. The rate limit appears to be around 10/s.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using Google API v2 which is deprecated as of now. Read the below post:

```
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/terms
```